# Ask feedback(formal)

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, politeness

I'm new here and I going to give a lot of questions in further =)
I and my friend make cartoons. And soon we will share the new one. So I want to ask people to give some feedback.

Which example is more correct (either grammatically or sounds polite)?

> 1) We would be glad **to see your feedback**. It helps us **make** our work faster.
>
> 2) We would be glad **if you could give some feedback**. It helps us **do** our work faster.

Comment: Are you sure that "faster" is the adverb you want?  Perhaps you mean "better"?

Comment: I mean we will make it with much bigger pleasure. So the work will be done faster. 
I think we will not do our work better than we can =) The result will be better with time and experience =)

Comment: *Your feedback is appreciated. It boosts our morale.*

Comment: There we are; I vote for @Maulik's example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one sounds foreign because

1. "See" is not the right verb for receiving feedback.  Try "have" or "get."
2. One does not "make" work in this context.  "Making work" is a negative phrase meaning someone is making your life difficult by giving you meaningless work to do.  "Do" is the right verb here.

The second one sounds fine, but a native speaker would be more likely to say "if you **would** give." Using the word "could" implies that you are uncertain whether the user is able to give feedback, while "would" implies that you do not yet know if they will choose to do so.

Maulik_V's suggestion of "your feedback is appreciated" is very common and natural.  Speaking of morale, I think, is unnecessary.  It's understood that feedback is helpful--you don't need to be personal about it.  My suggestion is simply

> Your feedback is appreciated.

or more explicitly

> Your feedback is helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will mark this answer as accepted =)